# How to call same subroutine from Perl module in different ways? What is Perl Module "Default mode"?

Tags: perl, wrapper, perl-module, overloading

I've written a perl module (say `foo`), with one primary subroutine (say `f()`), which I want to use in two ways:

1. Import module `foo` , then call the sub `f(...)` from the script importing module `foo`.
2. Just import module `foo` and get module `foo` to call the sub `f(@ARGV)` or some appropriate variation.

Can I make one module which has these two options,
or
Should I make a *wrapper module*, say `foo_default.pm`, which will `use foo` and then calls `foo::f(@ARGV)`?

Comment: Can you post some code that you tried for *some appropriate variation*? Because you can just export function as *sputnick* has shown you. and that will work for function call with arguments, just use `my $args = @_;` as first line in your function `f()`.

Answer (score 2):

### The Classic Way

If you don't want to provide the *fully qualified name* of your function, you should `export` it :

```
package foo;
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw/func1 func2/;

sub func1 { return "hi $_[0] !\n"; }
sub func2 { return "yo breakdown mama !\n"; }
```

So to use it :

```
# uncomment this if you need to add a "./lib" dir in @INC
# BEGIN{ push @INC, "./lib"; }

use foo;

my $res = func1("you");
print $res;
```

Answer (score 1):

Example foo module:

```
package foo;

my $nodef = 0;

sub import {
  my ($package, $arg) = @_; 
  print "import called $arg\n";
  $nodef = 1 if (defined $arg && $arg eq 'nodef');
  f(@ARGV) if !$nodef;
}

sub f() {
  print "f() called: ", join(", ", @_), "\n";
}

1;
```

And the use case:

```
sub def {
  use foo;
}

sub nodef {
  use foo qw(nodef);
}

def();
nodef();
```